# Creating a type that takes enum argument

Tags: typescript, generics, enums, type-constraints

I am trying to create a reusable type utilizing the `Record` type.

```
enum MyKeys {
  ALPHA = 'ALPHA',
  BETA = 'BETA',
  GAMMA = 'GAMMA',
}

interface MyValues {
  in: any[];
  out: any[];
}

type Case<T> = Record<T, MyValues>;
```

Ideally I can use `Case<MyKeys>` instead of `Record<MyKeys, MyValues>`.

> Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
>
> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'symbol'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type argument `T` needs to be constrained to a valid index type:

```
type Case<T extends string> = Record<T, MyValues>;
```

Comment: right, or `T extends keyof any` to be as unconstrained as possible.

Answer (score 3):

The only valid types that can be used for keys are strings, numbers, and symbols. TypeScript provides a built-in alias for such a union called `PropertyKey`.

The built-in Record type will accept only one of these. That's why your type constructor needs to have the same constraint as well.

```
type Case<T extends PropertyKey> = Record<T, MyValues>;
```